# How to get info of an FTPFile

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using ApacheCommons to connect to a server and get information of a specific file. I am looking for a method like `FTPFile file = ftpclient.getFile(path);` or something like this, so I can give it the path of the file and then be able to get info about that file. By info I mean `file.getName()` or `file.lendth()`.
The only way I found is using listing methods such as `listFiles(path)` but it requires using `for-loop` and so on. But is there any better way or more straight forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FTPClient.mlistFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistFile(java.lang.String)):

```
public FTPFile mlistFile(String pathname)
```

> Get file details using the MLST command

Of course, this will work only, if your server supports the [modern `MLST` command](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-7).

If not, you would have to use a dedicated command for each file property. Like the `SIZE` for file size (not supported natively by Apache Commons) or the `MDTM` for file modification time (the [`FTPClient.getModificationTime`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getModificationTime(java.lang.String))).