# Java Apache FTP client - Resume broken upload

Tags: java, ftp, upload, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I need to implement resuming of upload in my FTP client, if something went wrong. `ftp` in the example below is Apache [`FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

```
public boolean upload(InputStream localFile, String remoteName, boolean createNew) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(remoteName)) {
        log.warn("Error while uploading file: localFile or remoteName is null");
        return false;
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        try {

            if (createNew) {
                return ftp.storeFile(remoteName, localFile);
            } else {
                return ftp.appendFile(remoteName, localFile); //todo is it right?
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

So if `ftp.storeFile` crashes (not all bytes were sent e.g.), how can I continue uploading using the same `InputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- reconnect your FTP session (if it was broken too);
- test size of remote file to determine how many bytes made it all the way through to the remote disk (e.g. using [`FTPClient.mlistFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistFile(java.lang.String)) or `SIZE` command – See [How to get info of an FTPFile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29198422/850848));
- seek the "input stream" back to that point (though `InputStream` does not support seeking, so you will have to use a different stream implementation – or reopen the `InputStream` and [`skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip-long-) to the position);
- call `FTPClient.appendFile`.